# how get the option value $r['id_usr'] of select tag in PHP variable

Tags: php, jquery, html

I need to get the option value of a select tag which is `$r['usr_id']` when submitted to use that value in **php** query

**here is my code :**

```php
 <pre>
     <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 control-label">Piloté Par</label>
     <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">  
        <?php
        // LOGIN TO DATABASE SCRIPT WRITTEN FOR MYSQLI
        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "schb");
        if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
        }
        // END OF LOGIN TO DB SCRIPT

        $query_ak = "SELECT id_usr, nom_usr, pnom_usr FROM user WHERE role='Pilote processus' AND id_usr NOT IN (SELECT pilot_id FROM processus)";
        $result = $mysqli->query($query_ak);
        ?>
        <select class="form-control select" name="slctpilot" >
            <?php
            while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo '<option value="' . $r['id_usr'] . '">' . $r['nom_usr'] . ' ' . $r['pnom_usr'] . '</option>';
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
</pre>
```

Comment: I see no usages of jquery in this code example.

Comment: Where is form element ?? how you want pass this value to php via ajax or form submit ??

Comment: where is form element ?? and how you trying to pass this value to php by ajax or form submit??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the form is submitted (posted) store it in a variable -

```
$userId = $_POST['slctpilot'];
```

If `value="' . $r['id_usr'] . '"` -> `value='23'` the `$userId` will hold `23`.

Comment: this case will give $r['nam_usr']+$r['nam_usr'] not the  
$r['id']

Comment: It will return the value of selected option.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 echo '<option value="<?php echo $r['id_usr']; ?>" <?php $r['nom_usr'].$r['pnom_usr'];?></option>';
```

Comment: While this post may answer the question, it is still a good idea to add some explanation and, possibly, some links to the relevant documentation. Answers with good explanations and references are usually more useful both to the current OP and to the future visitors. Full detailed answers are also more likely to attract positive votes.

Answer (score 0):

You can get value of select field using following code ...

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
   $slctpilot = $_POST['slctpilot'];
}
```

Comment: this case will give $r['nam_usr']+$r['nam_usr'] not the id